# Intent throwing Null Value in the MainActivity from MainActivity2

Tags: android, kotlin

Main Activity 2 and Main Activity Code. If I pass the variable to MainActivity from MainActivity2 then I am getting null error in Kotlin.

*Main Activity2 Code*

```
class MainActivity2:AppCompatActivity()  {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        GetJsonWithOkHttpClient(this.text).execute();
        val test=GetJsonWithOkHttpClient(this.text).execute().get()
        System.out.println("ABC Value is $test")
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity2,MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Test",test)
        var jsonStringArray=intent.getStringExtra("Test")
        startActivity(intent)
        System.out.println("TestValue: $jsonStringArray")
    }
```

*Main Activity Code*

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
        var jsonStringArray=intent.getStringExtra("Test")
    }
```

Comment: Pleass Post your code

Comment: To show the code edit the question and add it as properly formatted text, not as image and not in the comments.

Comment: I don't see where variable `test` is set.

Comment: Added the correct code @mich

Answer (score 0):

remove

```
var jsonStringArray=intent.getStringExtra("Test")
```

from MainActivity2

```
 class MainActivity2: AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
         GetJsonWithOkHttpClient(this.text).execute();
         val test = GetJsonWithOkHttpClient(this.text).execute().get()
         System.out.println("ABC Value is $test")
         val intent = Intent(this @MainActivity2, MainActivity::class.java)
         intent.putExtra("Test", test)
         startActivity(intent)
         System.out.println("TestValue: $jsonStringArray")
     }
```

or

your main activity should be

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle ? ) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
val test="your value"
val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,MainActivity2::class.java) 
intent.putExtra("Test",test) 
}
}
```

Comment: I changed my MainActivity value as above but getting "Unresolved reference:  test" error

Comment: add val test="your value"

Comment: Thanks but still I am missing something.     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.codility.barchartgraph/com.codility.barchartgraph.MainActivity}: org.json.JSONException: Value Helllo of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
   
       val jsonStringArray="Helllo"
        val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,MainActivity2::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("Test",jsonStringArray)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sasikumar, I am able to resolve this issue by using below code. Thank you all for your help.   val test= MainActivity2.GetJsonWithOkHttpClient(this.text).execute().get(). I changed my text ID between Main Activity and Main Activity 2.